# Facebook notification from my app appears and disappears

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, notifications

I have a problem since a several days now. Facebook notifications from my app (the red number one) appears and disappears. This functioning properly at first, but then but then stopped working.
I tried by entering in the Website url -> http://mipagina.com, in the canvas url -> http://mipagina.com/ and the secure url https.... I tried many other ways but nothing. I realized that the app request don't send a notification to the user for his acceptance. But I can add the app from the app page. If the user add the app the red number one appears and then disappears but the notification from my app shows in the facebook notifications page. But if the user doesn't add the app, the red number one appears and then disappears and then the notification doesn't appear in the facebook notifications page. 
Hope you can help me...Please sorry for my english.

Comment: is your application in sandbox mode?

Comment: No Lix, sandbox it's disabled...

Comment: Yes, I try by entering in the Website url http://mipagina.com, and in the canvas url http://mipagina.com/app_face and the secure url https://mipagina.com/app_face

Comment: I have the same problem, request shows in menu, but red number appears and disappears in a second. Trying to figure out

Comment: I have the same problem. I send an invitation to one friend. 
The invitation is created: I get a request_id and using this request_id with the open graph I can retrieve the request data, so its correctly sent. The receiver sees a red "1" number appear on the world icon, but when he opens the notifications, the number dissapears and there is no invitation. A few days ago it worked fine! Did you get a solution?

Comment: @kobayashi , i know its been long time..did u find any solution to fix this problem am also facing the same

Answer (score 2):

Since "user-to-user requests are only available in canvas apps" ([see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/)), you must make sure your canvas app is properly set up.

Review that you have done ALL of the following steps:

- Set *Sandbox Mode* to off
- Selected a *Namespace* for your app
- Enabled *App on Facebook* (which is the canvas app settings)
- Filled out *Canvas URL* and *Secure Canvas URL*

Facebook will not notify you in its Javascript API about these issues: there it will seem like the app request notification has indeed successfully been delivered.